# Atrocious font rendering in Firefox on Linux

Tags: linux, firefox, fonts

Firefox (actually Iceweasel since I'm on Debian) fails to render some texts properly. It only seems to happen on some sites, for example on Stack Exchange sites everything looks pretty normal. I don't have the same issue when running Firefox on Windows.

This is what it looks like on Firefox:

[image]

For comparison, this is how Chromium renders the same text:

[image]

How can I fix this?

I'm running Iceweasel 44.0 on Debian x64.

Comment: For anyone trying to reproduce this: this happened to me on http://www.deepin.org/aboutus.html. Not adding this link to the question because the problem occurs on other sites as well. (Also, it won't let me add a third link)

Comment: Just FYI, you can install actual Firefox on Debian and keep it maintained to the current release by the package manager.  There's a Debian-based Mint, and their repository has it.  You just add that repository and install it from there.

Comment: The Wuhan Deepin Technology Co., Ltd. webpage in your question looks the same in Firefox as it does in Ieweasel, so installing Firefox instead of Iceweasel wouldn't change the appearance of that webpage.

Comment: @karel: OK, it doesn't solve that particular problem (which, granted, was the reason for the question).  However, there are plenty of other shortcomings with Iceweasel that can be solved by switching.  So I guess my previous comment would just be advice to keep in a back pocket for a rainy day.

Comment: I looked at that web page in Firefox (V43.0) in Debian and the text looks fine.  There must be some form of rendering issue on your system (and karel's).  Hopefully, somebody with some coding background will be able to diagnose the problem.

Comment: I tested the real Firefox, and just like karel said, it looks exactly the same. (Also, where can I learn more about the other shortcomings with Iceweasel you mentioned? I thought it was just a renamed Firefox.)

Comment: If you "address" a comment to a specific user, like @fixer1234, they will receive an alert to your posting.  Otherwise, nobody will be aware of it unless they stumble across it.  There's something else going on causing the font problem because it happens on some systems but not others.  It's probably something ancillary rather than the browser, itself, like an outdated version of Java, something related to the font file, etc.  One thing to try is starting FF/Iceweasel in safe mode to rule out a plug-in/extension problem.   (cont'd)

Comment: Beyond that, it will take someone with some coding background to identify what the cause might be, perhaps by looking at the page source to see what might affect the rendering.  re: Iceweasel, supposedly, the only difference is branding.  However, nothing gets into Debian (stable) without extensive testing, and Debian does the rebranding work, so applications tend to be old versions by the time they're released.  Most of the issues I ran into with Iceweasel related to it simply being way out of date.

Answer (score 1):

See reply #7 here:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/kubuntu-kde4-meta/+bug/1196954/comments/7

Basically `rm ~/.config/fontconfig/fonts.conf`

This worked for me.